# Convolution with zero mean using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

How do you go about implementing a `conv2d` where each filter has a zero mean.

I tried to do this via the `kernel_regularizer` argument in `conv2d` for but am running into issues for some reason.

```py
def zero_mean_regularizer(weight_matrix):
    # weight matrix is channel last
    return weight_matrix - K.mean(weight_matrix, axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True)
```

For some reason though, I'm getting a mysterious error from the ModelCheckpoint callback.

```py
self = <keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint object at 0x12e890358>, epoch = 0
logs = {'loss': array([[[[-0.24377288,  0.4010657 ,  0.03990834, -0.19173835,
           0.02325685, -0.12445911,  0.34307766...0454,  0.18098758,  0.05493904,
          -0.15479018, -0.19435076,  0.07913151,  0.20207654]]]],
      dtype=float32)}

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        self.epochs_since_last_save += 1
        if self.epochs_since_last_save >= self.period:
            self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
            filepath = self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)
            if self.save_best_only:
                current = logs.get(self.monitor)
                if current is None:
                    warnings.warn('Can save best model only with %s available, '
                                  'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
                else:
>                   if self.monitor_op(current, self.best):
E                   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Seems as if this regularizer is causing the model to create multiple loss values for a single epoch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use this as a *constraint*, not a regularizer. A regularizer should return a scalar value that is added to the loss. This would *encourage* certain behavior (by rewarding it with a lower loss), but not *enforce* it.

Likely, Keras is trying to add the return argument of the regularizer (the 0-mean kernels) to the loss, which results in a non-scalar loss value, which in turn leads to problems down the line (and doesn't really make any sense).

A `kernel_constraint`, on the other hand, is a function that takes the current kernel and returns a new value that may be in some way modified, such as being forced to mean 0.

tl;dr: In your model code, use the zero mean function as `kernel_constraint`, not as a regularizer.